# Ruby not edit or saving from a collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help 
The form does not save the collection_select and it does not edit 
_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :company_id %><br />
  <%= collection_select(:learner, :learner_id, @clients, :id, :name,    prompt: >true) %> 
</div>
```

learners_controller.rb

```
def new
    @learner = Learner.new
    @clients = Client.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @learner }
    end
  end
  # GET /learners/1/edit
  def edit
  @learner = Learner.find(params[:learner][:learner_id])
  end

  # POST /learners
  # POST /learners.json
  def create
    @learner = Learner.new(learner_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @learner.save
        format.html { redirect_to @learner, notice: 'Learner was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @learner }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @learner.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /learners/1
  # PATCH/PUT /learners/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @learner.update(learner_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @learner, notice: 'Learner was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @learner }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @learner.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: how params looks like ? post it here yr console log

Comment: Started GET "/learners/4/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-09 10:44:24 +0200
Processing by LearnersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
  [1m[35mLearner Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "learners".* FROM "learners" WHERE "learners"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  [1m[36mLearner Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "learners".* FROM "learners" WHERE "learners"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Learner with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/learners_controller.rb:27:in `edit'

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do:

```
def edit
  @learner = Learner.find(params[:learner][:learner_id])
end
```

To find the record of learner.

Comment: Nope getting error 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass'

Answer (score 0):

From the parameters you posted in the comment, the edit route is passing in the ID as just `:id`, so the edit action should be:

```
def edit
  @learner = Learner.find(params[:id])
end
```

As for the form not saving your `collection_select` input, it looks like you are using the default [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem with Rails 4. This means that `learner_id` must be available in the list of whitelisted parameters. At the bottom of your controller should be the `learner_params` method.

```
def learner_params
  params.require(:learner).permit(...other parameters..., :learner_id)
end
```